Haskell code for square root of negative integers
How can I use Haskell to find the square root of a negative integer?

StackOverflow is not a code translation service. Make a fair attempt to translate the code and come back with specific problems with that translation.

I have modified the question as per the comments.

As it currently stands, I believe this is a specific (focused) and legitimate question. from review

@Al.G. I disagree, as it stands it looks like "do my work for me" even more than when it included code in a different language.

Yes, I agree about the lack of research effort. It's just that it's not unfocused. I guess I could have changed the close reason instead of approving.

I understand that the current version of the question does not apparently indicate any research effort or it may appear not useful. Otherwise, the question is not unclear.
Based on the answer by willeM_ Van Onsem, I want to convey that square root of a negative integer is not obvious for a Haskell learner unlike square root of a positive integer. Standard Haskell text books do not discuss this topic. It is also not covered in HaskellWiki (wiki.haskell.org/). I had put effort to find answers.
When I search for "square root negative number Haskell" in Google, this page comes on the top.

You can use the sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a function [Hackage] where you work with a Complex type [Hackage]:
ghci> sqrt (-4) :: Complex Float
0.0 :+ 2.0
ghci> sqrt 4 :: Complex Float
2.0 :+ 0.0
so this means 0 + 2i and 2 + 0i respectively.

import Data.Complex is required.
